# regex linkify urls ignoring existing links

Tags: html, regex

I have built a regex that puts an anchor tag around urls that look like this:

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://google.com
```

It ignores case and it also ignores urls already in links, such as:

```
<a href="hTTP://www.google.com">HttP://www.google.com</a>
```

The last little bit I need to do is to linkify a url that is not preceed by the protocol, but at least begins with www., such as:

```
www.google.com
```

My saved regex can be seen and tweaked here:

https://regex101.com/r/Rf3HF8/1

And here is the actual regex:

```
(?i)(?<!")http(s)?:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*+)(?!<\/a>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say which flavor of regex you're using.  Hopefully something with working negative lookbehind, like PCRE:

Combining and expanding from the previous answers:

```
(?<!["']>|["'])(?:(?:https?:\/\/)|(?<!\/\/)www\.|(?:https?::\/\/)www\.)(?:\w+\.)+\w+(?:\/[a-z0-9-._~:\/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]*)?
```

Play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/jCpbgi/1

This should work on a large variety of URLs and domain names, and doesn't match previously-linkified URLs.

Comment: This works great for my needs.  But, how can it be expanded to also match on something like:  testmedia.company.com/books/123456/789456/contents.html

Comment: The more generic you make the inputs, the more likely it is to catch false positives.  Fiddle around with the "www\." portions carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

`((?:http(s)?(:\/\/)))?((?:www\.)?)([\w-]+)(\.)(com)`

Breaking it down:

- `((?:http(s)?(:\/\/)))?` - optional match on `http`, `https` plus the `://` but not `://` on its own
- `((?:www\.)?)` - optional match on `www.`
- `([\w-]+)` - match one or more [a-zA-Z_] and hyphen - this is for the `google` part
- `(\.)` - match a `.` for example between the `google` and `com`
- `(com)` - just match the `com` part

The regex fully matches the following examples:

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://google.com
https://google.com
www.google.com
www.google-blah.com
```

Only partial matches for:

```
://www.foo.com
http://sub.domain.com
```

Saved here: https://regex101.com/r/vlYZ5N/1

Fancy diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown and the diagram.  Very helpful for regex neophites such as myself.